# Split elements of a list and retrieve only the first part from the split

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list say

```
List<string> someList = new List{"1-30","20-10","21-23","34-80"};
```

I need to split the list so I have with following values

```
 {"1","20","21","34"};
```

I tried

```
 someList
   .SelectMany(n => n.Split('-')[0])
   .ToList();
```

But it is not giving me the desired result.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry everyone, Using `Select` solved my issue. One of those days, when you make silly mistakes

Comment: What does it return then? Why are you using `SelectMany()` instead of `Select()`?

Comment: Oops sorry, Select worked. I think i need coffee

Comment: `'1-30','20-100','21-23','34-80'` this aren't string at all and thus your code line `List<string> someList = new List{'1-30','20-100','21-23','34-80'};` shouldn't compile in first place

Comment: @CodeCaster is correct - by using `SelectMany()`, you are flattening out the prefixes back into a sequence of Characters. `Select()` will preserve the prefixes as strings.

Comment: yes thanks found the mistake @StuartLC

Comment: @Rahul i was just trying to give a gist of my problem

Comment: @wingskush Never in a developer's life comes the time when they don't need more coffee :-)

Comment: As you correctly spotted with the help of comment .. your only issue was using `SelectMany()`

Answer (score 4):

You have to take the *1st part* of each item and you can do with a help of `Substring` (i.e. take item's value up to `-`):

```
 List<string> someList = new List{
   "1-30", "20-100", "21-23", "34-80"};

 var result = someList
   .Select(item => item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf('-')))
   .ToList(); // if you want a new list
```

In case you want to change the *existing list*, just implement a loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < someList.Count; ++i)
   someList[i] = someList[i].Substring(0, someList[i].IndexOf('-'));
```

**Edit:** what's going on when you put `SelectMany` instead of `Select`.

`SelectMany` wants `IEnumerable<T>` as an outcome and since `String` is `IEnumerable<char>` you have a flatten `List<char>`s:

```
   ['1', '2', '0', '2', '1', '3', '4']
```

Please, notice that each string (`"1", "20", "21", "34"`) is treated as being a *collection* of chars (`['1']; ['2', '0']; ['2', '1']; ['3', '4']`)

Comment: @wingskush: `SelectMany` wants an *enumerator* as an output, e.g. `SelectMany(`item => ... someCollection)`; in your case you have string which is a *collection* of `char`: `IEnumerable<char>` and so you have the misbehaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use selectMany since you don't need to flatten your list. Using Select will return each string in the list

> {"1-30", "20-100"...etc}

. Using SelectMany will actually flatten the strings into a sequence of chars resulting in

> {"1", "-", "3", "0" ...etc}

So your split will result in the wrong result.

.

You just select each item in your list, split the item on the '-' char and select the first result from the split. This should give you the correct result.

```
List<string> someList = new List<string> { "1-30", "20-100", "21-23", "34-80" };
var splitString = someList.Select(x => x.Split('-').First()).ToList();
```

Comment: I didn't see CodeCasters comment. Will update my answer

Comment: @StuartLC, agree but why credit CodeCaster? it's not a copy of his answer. He just commented and that's his own opinion

Comment: @StuartLC clarification added

Answer (score -1):

Not as pretty as you probably want, but it does the work.

```
List<string> someList = new List<string>{"1-30","20-100","21-23","34-80"};
List<string> newList = new List<string>();
foreach (var v in someList)
     {
        string[] s = v.Split('-');
        newList.Add(s[0]);
     }
```